# Add Usr Custom Field to Acumatica Appointments Mobile App

Tags: mobile, acumatica, appointment

I'm trying to add a custom field to the mobile application Appointments screen FS300200. It seems simple where I update the containers and add the field but it's not showing up on the screen. For testing purposes, I was able to edit the display name of a field in the same container so my acumatica instance is talking to the mobile app okay. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? The field name is UsrUnitNbr (display name Unit Nbr. and I confirmed this in web services). I've tried:
add field "UnitNbr"
add field "UsrUnitNbr"
add field "Unit Nbr".

Here is the full command from the mobile app portion of the customization project editor

```
update screen FS300200 {
update container"AppointmentRecords" {
    update layout "AppointmentHeader" {
        update layout "AppointmentHeaderNbrRow" {

 add field "UnitNbr"{displayName ="Unit Nbr."}
      }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing....the blue area at the top of the appt mobile screen is the container AppointmentRecords.  Notice the layout tag = "HeaderSimple".  This means fields inside this container is read only.  Try to add your user field here.

```
update layout "ServiceOrderNbrLine" {
 displayName = "ServiceOrderNbrLine"
     layout = "Inline"
     add field "UsrUnitNbr"
}
```